# Hartshorne Exercise I.3.17 (e): Normalization of Affine Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Hartshorne, namely Exercise I.3.17 (e):

> (e) Let $Y$ be an affine variety. Show that there is a normal affine variety $\widetilde{Y}$, and a morphism $\pi\colon\widetilde{Y}\to Y$, with the propery that whenever $Z$ is a normal variety, and $\varphi\colon Z\to Y$ is a *dominant* morphism (i.e., $\varphi(Z)$ is dense in $Y$), then there is a unique morphism $\theta\colon Z\to\widetilde{Y}$ such that $\varphi=\pi\circ\theta$. $\widetilde{Y}$ is called the *normalization of $Y$*. You will need (3.9A) above.

Here's my attempt:

Let $A = A(Y)$. By Finiteness of Integral Closure (Theorem 3.9A), we have that $\overline{A}$ is an affine domain. Thus there is an affine variety $\widetilde{Y}$ with $A(\widetilde{Y}) = \overline{A}$. Furthermore, $\widetilde{Y}$ is normal. The canonical inclusion $A\hookrightarrow \overline{A}$ gives rise to morphism $\pi: \widetilde{Y}\to Y$. Now, suppose $Z$ is another normal variety, which a dominant morphism $\varphi : Z\to Y$. This induces an inclusion of function fields in the opposite direction $K(Y)\hookrightarrow K(Z)$, which I'll call $\varphi^{\sharp}$. Since $A(Z)$ is integrally closed, $\varphi^{\sharp}$ induces a unique map $A(\widetilde{Y}) = \overline{A}\to A(Z)$ such that the diagram
$$ \begin{array}{cc}
A(\widetilde{Y})&\hookleftarrow A(Y)\\
\downarrow\varphi^{\sharp}&\swarrow_{\varphi^{\sharp}}\\
A(Z)
\end{array}$$
commutes. (The maps labelled $\varphi^{\sharp}$ above are just the relevant restrictions of $\varphi^{\sharp}$.)

Finally, we consider the above in the equivalent opposite category of affine varieties and we are done.

I would be very grateful if someone could point out mistakes in my attempt, or confirm that it's correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use images: they are not searchable, they are not accessible, and they do not adapt to the reader's display. It is better to type up the material.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Please excuse me for now, I will try to type the problems next time onward.

Comment: It would be better if you took the effort to fix this one, but since you are unwilling, I will do it for you.

Comment: This is essentially correct but more than a bit light on the justification for *why* you get the factorization triangle that you claim. If you were a student turning this in for an assignment and I was your instructor, I would complain.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, yes, I see what you mean. To fix that, is the following sufficient: Since $A(Z)$ is integrally closed, and contains (an isomorphic image of) $A(Y)$, $A(Z)$ must contain all the elements of $K(Z)$ integral over $A(Y)$. But since $K(Z)$ contains an isomorphic image of $K(Y)$ inside itself, $\varphi^{\sharp}(A(\tilde{Y}))\subset K(Z)$, and is integral over $A(Y)$, and thus contained in $A(Z)$. All that I've just said, about inclusions and containment, is with respect to $\varphi^{\sharp}:K(Y)\hookrightarrow K(Z)$, and since $A(Y)\subset A(\tilde{Y})\subset K(Y)$,  we're done.

Comment: Sorry for being unable to frame the comment above very well, had to stick to the limit on the permitted number of characters in a single comment.

Comment: To consider category of affine varieties, doesn't Z need to be affine as well? I don't think it that part was given.

Comment: @Abastro That's correct, but you can use Hartshorne Proposition I.3.5